# Find x (star-geometric problem)

Tags: geometry

Find x using only facts about the sum of internal and external angles of triangles.

[image]

Comment: We can build many different triangles from two "points" of the star and one "point" of the interior pentagon.  Using that the sum of the interior angles of the triangles sum to $180$, we should be able to get all but 1 interior angle of the pentagon.  Can you find this?  After you find this, use the first method to find a triangle involving the point $x$, a known point, and a known interior angle of the pentagon, and solve for $x$.

I'd write up a solution but don't see a good way notionally to do it without pictures, which I can't really make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the angles of a 5-pointed star is equal to $180$, therefore $x=33$

[image]